# Cycle through iterable and keep only relevant elements

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

**Background:**
I have the following for python 3

```
data = [{'name': 'Jon','id_str': '01'},{'name': 'Tom','id_str': '02'}, {'name': 'Jim','id_str': '03'}] 
id = ['01','1133', '02', '2222']
```

**Goal**: Keep `data` when `id` == `id_str` and append to a list.

The code below appends the first `data` point `[{'id_str': '01', 'name': 'Jon'}]` (which is what I want)

```
id_list = [] 
for d in range(len(data)):
    t = data[d]          
    id_str = t['id_str']       

    if id_str == id[d]: 
        keep = data[d]  
        id_list.append(keep)
```

**Problem**: Now I want to move onto the next `id` in the list `'1133'`. But since the second `id` value `'1133'` does not equal the `id_str` for the second value in `data` (`{'name': 'Tom','id_str': '02'}`, I want it to skip this and move on to the third value in `id`  which is `'02'`. Since `id ('02')` is equal to `id_str` (`{'name': 'Tom','id_str': '02'}`)  I want to append.

I want to continue this process and cycle until all of the `id = ['01','1133', '02', '2222']` are checked. This website http://love-python.blogspot.com/2012/03/get-next-element-from-list-in-python.html. suggests that I should add a counter at some point, along with `if-else` statements but I've tried many times and I'm not sure how.

I would guess my final code would look something like the following

```
id_list = [] 
for d in range(len(data)):
    t = data[d]          
    id_str = t['id_str']       

    if id_str == id[d]: 
        keep = data[d]  
        id_list.append(keep)

    elif id_str != id_list[d]: 
         skip 
         check next id
    else:
         if no more id to check
         break
```

**Desired final output:**

```
[{'name': 'Jon','id_str': '01'},{'name': 'Tom','id_str': '02'}]
```

**Question:** How do I accomplish these goals:

1) keep and append desired data (when `id == id_str`)

2) skip unwanted data (when `id != id_str`)

3) break when finished cycling through `id` 
(that is, once all of the elements in `id = ['01','1133', '02', '2222']` are indexed and compared to all `id_str` in `data`)

Comment: Instead of `if id_str == id[d]:` do `if id_str in id`

Comment: what if you have multiple dictionaries in the original list that have the same, valid, `'id_str'`? Do you take both?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "break when finished cycling through `id`" ?

Comment: @jpp  I meant once all of the elements in `id = ['01','1133', '02', '2222']` are indexed and compared to all `id_str` in `data`

Comment: Ah I see, understood. So I think the solution is correct. We are just making sure all elements are checked. Thks for clarification.

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: @EER If `data` was `[{'name': 'Jon','id_str': '01'},{'name': 'Tom','id_str': '01'}`, what should the result be?

Comment: good question. This would return an empty list, `[ ]`. But luckily all my i`d_str` are unique in the actual dataset that I am using so this shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using a list comprehension.

```
data = [{'name': 'Jon','id_str': '01'},{'name': 'Tom','id_str': '02'}, {'name': 'Jim','id_str': '03'}] 
ids = ['01','1133', '02', '2222']

res = [d for d in data if d['id_str'] in ids]

# [{'id_str': '01', 'name': 'Jon'}, {'id_str': '02', 'name': 'Tom'}]
```

Comment: @jpp this does not seem as correct as OP thinks. I think. xD

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `filter` function:

```
 id_list = filter(lambda x: x['id_str'] in id, data)
```

This doesn't allow you to stop early, but the original data list isn't designed for the query you want. You can only ask what the `id_str` of an item is; you can't get an item with a given `id_str` without scanning the list.

(For Python 3, `id_list` will be an iterator, not a list; use `id_list = list(filter(...))` instead.)

Comment: for Python 3, this has to be wrapped in a `list` constructor.

Comment: True; however, my bigger concern with this answer is that it doesn't meet criteria 3, which is to stop iterating once all of the matched items are found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if id_str == id[d]:` do `if id_str in id`.

In addition to this, I suggest another change: you can loop over a list directly instead of looping over indices like you do in many other languages.

```
for t in data:
    id_str = t['id_str']

    if id_str in id:
        keep = data[d]  
        id_list.append(keep)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers that have been posted are great but do not respect your 3rd (rather ambiguous) condition.

The following does:

```
res = [y for y in [next((d for d in data if d['id_str'] == x), {}) for x in id] if y]
```

---

**But,**

I am assuming here that you want to use the items in `id` exactly once. This has the following consequence:

> If your initial list has dictionaries with the same, valid, `id_str`,
>   only one of them will be included in `res` and there is no way of
>   knowing *which one* (dicts are not ordered!)

Answer (score 0):

I think using list comprehension works fine for you:

```
data = [{'name': 'Jon','id_str': '01'},{'name': 'Tom','id_str': '02'}, {'name': 'Jim','id_str': '03'}] 
id = ['01','1133', '02', '2222']

out = [d for d in data if d['id_str'] in id]
print(out)
```

But if you want a more procedural way this might suite you better:

```
def id_filter(data, id):
    out = []
    for d in data:
        if d['id_str'] in id:
            out.append(d)
    return out
print(id_filter(data, id))
```